# Keep getting "Invalid Content-Range" response from AWS Glacier Multipart Upload

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I can't figure out why I keep getting an invalid Content-Range from AWS Glacier. It looks to me like my format follows RFC 2616 but I keep getting an error. Help?

[image]

Here's the code:

```
using (var FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(ARCHIVE_FILE, FileMode.Open))
{
    while (FileStream.Position < FileInfo.Length)
    {
        string Range = "Content-Range:bytes " + FileStream.Position.ToString() + "-" + (FileStream.Position + Size - 1).ToString() + "/*";

        var request = new Amazon.Glacier.Model.UploadMultipartPartRequest()
        {
            AccountId = "-",
            VaultName = VAULT_NAME,
            Body = Amazon.Glacier.GlacierUtils.CreatePartStream(FileStream, Size),
            UploadId = UploadId,
            Range = Range,
            StreamTransferProgress = Progress
        };
        //request.SetRange(FileStream.Position, FileStream.Position + Size - 1);
        response = GlacierClient.UploadMultipartPart(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I misinterpreted the Intellisense description:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Identifies the range of bytes in the assembled archive that will be uploaded
//     in this part. Amazon Glacier uses this information to assemble the archive
//     in the proper sequence. The format of this header follows RFC 2616. An example
//     header is Content-Range:bytes 0-4194303/*.
```

You're not supposed to include the name of the header itself so this line:

```
string Range = "Content-Range:bytes " + FileStream.Position.ToString() + "-" + (FileStream.Position + Size - 1).ToString() + "/*";
```

Should be:

```
string Range = "bytes " + FileStream.Position.ToString() + "-" + (FileStream.Position + Size - 1).ToString() + "/*";
```

Derp.

Comment: In your defense, including that weird string formatting requirement is the worst. Thanks for posting - I was terribly confused until I found this! Note that this applies to JavaScript and other AWS SDKs as well.

Comment: Ran into this using the Python SDK.